# My Visual Studio 2008 web application keeps throwing a .Net error when I first run it, but refreshing fixes it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

As stated in the title my web application builds successfully, although every time I run it in debug mode I get the following .Net error:

[image: img]

If I hit refresh then the application gets no more errors until I next start it up again, any ideas?

Here is my global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="MyCompany.Web.MyApp.Shell.CustomWebClientApplication" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Session_End(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            Response.Redirect(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HomePage"]);
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Exception oops = Server.GetLastError();

        //Injection attack error handling
        if (oops.GetBaseException() is System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like WebClientApplication is expecting some sort of initialization?

Answer (score 2):

You have something which is trying to access a variable which is set to null (or hasn't been initialized).  Do you have anything in the Global.asax or anything that fires on the start of the application?  Do you have any asynchronous operations that fire on the start of the application?

Check on your Home.aspx page to see what is happening there.  It looks like your application redirects to that page, so I would guess that on either the init or page_load event there is something which is executing that it causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Exception oops
```

I think that this is source of problems. When there is no object returned from

```
Server.GetLastError();
```

then you will get NullReferenceException on line

```
oops.GetBaseException()
```

It makes perfect sense. On first run, oops is null (because no error occured before), thus throwing NullReferenceException. On second page refresh, GetLastError() returns object reffering previous errror (NullReferenceException) and page is displayed. Always check objects for null before accessing them.

Anyway, you can always try catching all runtime exceptions (Debug->Exceptions->Common Language runtime) and see where a problem is.

Comment: Nope this wasn't the problem.  I commented out everything within Application_Error then put a breakpoint on Application_Error.  When I first run the application it automatically hits this breakpoint then when I step further into it, the error occurs within the following method:

protected override void DefaultProcessBrowsers(bool ignoreApplicationBrowsers, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers, System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browserCaps) {
this.DefaultrefbrowseridAProcess(headers, browserCaps);
if (ignoreApplicationBrowsers) {
}
...
}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an initialization issue. You're probably trying to use a resource before it's initialized, but by the time you refresh it's had time to be initialized.